# Java get file path in resources fail in jar

Tags: java, apache-spark

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Config {
    public static final String CONFIG_FILE = "config.properties";
    public static final String KAFKA_JKS = "kafka.truststore.jks";

    public static Properties getProp() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_FILE);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
            return prop;
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + CONFIG_FILE + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
    }

    public static String getPath(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        URL fileURL = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
        if (fileURL != null) {
            return fileURL.getPath();
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
    }
}
```

I can run it in my **IDE** without any error , but when I package it as **jar**  I got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:702)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:557)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:540)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.createConsumer(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.<init>(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createContinuousReader(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createContinuousReader(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:185)
    at com.yizhisec.bigdata.KafkaStructStream.initStructKafka(KafkaStructStream.java:55)
    at com.yizhisec.bigdata.KafkaStructStream.run(KafkaStructStream.java:62)
    at com.yizhisec.bigdata.KafkaStructStream.main(KafkaStructStream.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:904)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/root/bigdata-1.0.jar!/kafka_client.truststore.jks (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:70)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:623)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/root/bigdata-1.0.jar!/kafka_client.truststore.jks (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:41)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/root/bigdata-1.0.jar!/kafka_client.truststore.jks (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory$SecurityStore.load(SslFactory.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory$SecurityStore.access$000(SslFactory.java:190)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.createSSLContext(SslFactory.java:134)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:108)
    ... 25 more
```

Then I unzip my jar with `unzip bigdata-1.0.jar -d temp_bigdata` and find it in `temp_bigdata/kafka_client.truststore.jks`. So the jar contains the file.

But it work well in IDE. I want to know that why run it fail in server but well in IDE and how to fix the error

Comment: @ScaryWombat can't work for me , second answer not work ,the first answer is funny that I only need a path why I should read it(I will try ). I need a jar include all the things I need

Comment: Resources are not files and don't have file paths. You can get the input stream, and that's all you should need.